# How to retrieve key/value from a JSON response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I understand we can use following to process a simple ajax JSON response

```
function onSuccess(response) {
    console.log("Service call successful with response"+response);
    $.each(response, function (key, value) {
        console.log(key+" "+value);

    }) ;
```

But, how to process to an array of JSON response like below?

```
{
   "xyzs":[
      {
         "xyz":{
            "id":"515f08380364db3bbe5a27f1",
            "xyz_id":"320224817603309569"
         }
      },
      {
         "xyz":{
            "id":"5161f9880364db3bbea86595",
            "xyz_id":"321033680736886784"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

onSuccess() function doesn't give expected output `id` and `xyz_id` in console with above response.

Is there some `for` loop in javascript which I use in `onSuccess()` function to get values of id and xyz_id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
var response = {
   "xyzs":[
      {
         "xyz":{
            "id":"515f08380364db3bbe5a27f1",
            "xyz_id":"320224817603309569"
         }
      },
      {
         "xyz":{
            "id":"5161f9880364db3bbea86595",
            "xyz_id":"321033680736886784"
         }
      }
   ]
};

$.each(response.xyzs, function () {
    var cur = this.xyz;
    console.log(cur.id, cur.xyz_id);
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/abBcW/

Comment: +1. It worked! thanks for code example as well. I wonder why Kundan's solution didn't work, only difference, he didn't use var cur=this.xyz

Answer (score 4):

You can try this instead :

```
$.each(response.xyzs, function (index, obj) {
   console.log(obj.xyz.id+" "+obj.xyz.xyz_id);
}) ;
```

Hope this will help !!

Comment: +1 for quick response. But, I don't know what's wrong happening, I get 2 lines of "undefined undefined" in console for the given JSON in question. I still don't get expected value of id and xyz_id

Comment: @Watt, i missed the **xyz** node, updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

In your case. you are having a json object, and $.each() will apply to a json array.

So you can get JSON array by `response.xyzs` and can loop through each element of that array.

```
 $.each(response.xyzs, function (key, value) {
        console.log(key+" "+value);   
    }) ;
```

Here is more clear JSON array looping example.

```
var data = [ 
 {"Id": 10004, "PageName": "club"}, 
 {"Id": 10040, "PageName": "qaz"}, 
 {"Id": 10059, "PageName": "jjjjjjj"}
];

$.each(data, function(i, item) {
    alert(data[i].PageName);
});​

$.each(data, function(i, item) {
    alert(item.PageName);
});​
```